# it seems that the version of the libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' file seen at compile-time

Tags: python, traceback

This traceback mess up all my program and I still cant fix it I have tried all methods and it didn't help!

Here's the problem:

> ffi_prep_closure(): bad user_data (it seems that the version of the
> libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' file seen
> at compile-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [cffi](https://pypi.org/project/cffi/#files) python package issue. Try to download the source package tar.gz from https://pypi.org/project/cffi/#files and install it manually using:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I get another error:
```
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   15 | #include <ffi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I get the same!

Answer (score 16):

This happens on some recent linux distributions - the binary wheel published on PyPI is not compatible with system libffi. Following will reinstall the package and build it locally on the system without using precompiled binaries published on PyPI:

```
pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary :all: cffi
```

PS: Installing `libffi-dev` (.deb based distros such as Ubuntu or Debian) or `libffi-devel` (.rpm based distros such as Fedora) might be needed before this.

Comment: To note, this worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 with GCloud SDK 370.0.0.

Comment: To note, this worked for me on Windows 11 with WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04 with Google Cloud SDK 371.0.0, also installed `libffi-dev` too.

Comment: Worked for me on Kubuntu 20.04 with GCloud SDK 372.0.0

Answer (score 10):

The problem also maybe be in a **python version**. I am using **Fedora Linux**, and it is always one python version ahead before `gcloud`. So I had `python3.10` and then I installed supported by `google-cloud-sdk` `python3.9` and pointed google-cloud-sdk to that version of python by adding a new path to `.bashrc`: `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.9`

Comment: Solved the problem with gcloud on Fedora 35 for me. `sudo dnf install python3.9`, `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.9 gcloud ...`

Answer (score 6):

I just did an upgrade and now the error dissapeared:

```
pip install --upgrade cffi xcffib
```

You might have to use `su` (or `sudo su`) before actually doing the update depending on what packages setup you want to target.

PS: I'm on Ubuntu so I used `su` before actually doing the upgrade

Comment: Thanks, I had to `sudo` too

Comment: This worked (without `sudo`) running a vanilla Debian bookworm system with `conda` managing the relevant python install.

Comment: This worked, got it working once I used sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on my Solaris box while building python itself.
Exporting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` had resolved the issue.