# Getting an error while passing the command 'gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=gcp_creds.json

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am getting the below error while trying to activate the service account. (GCP platform).

Running the command `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=gcp_creds.json` on ubuntu server.

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (SystemError): ffi_prep_closure(): bad user_data (it seems that the version of the libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' file seen at compile-time)`

Can anybody help me with this please? is it something related to the 'libffi' library that i need to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: `pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary :all: cffi`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [it seems that the version of the libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' file seen at compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658237/it-seems-that-the-version-of-the-libffi-library-seen-at-runtime-is-different-fro)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658237/it-seems-that-the-version-of-the-libffi-library-seen-at-runtime-is-different-fro

Comment: I tried both the commands
pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary :all: cffi and
pip install --upgrade cffi xcffib
```(remote-exec): Successfully built xcffib
 (remote-exec): Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, xcffib
 (remote-exec): Successfully installed cffi-1.15.0 pycparser-2.21 xcffib-0.11.1```
i see it is succesfully installed but issue remains the same
```ERROR: gcloud crashed (SystemError): ffi_prep_closure(): bad user_data (it seems that the version of the libffi library seen at runtime is different from the 'ffi.h' file seen at compile-time)```